# How to refresh page on back button using preventBack () function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code blocks going to back and sends forward:

```
function preventBack() {
    window.history.forward();
}

setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
window.onunload = function() {
    null
};
```

Is it possible when user goes to another website from my website and tries to come back, my website get refreshed before loading?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "refreshed before loading".

Comment: `setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);` should be `setTimeout(preventBack, 0);`